# Tuning the cost of data transfer with NGINX

Tags: nginx, streaming, data-transfer

I have a streaming setup using ngnix and i would like to know how to fine tune the data transfer, say i have the following in this diagram.

[image]

You can see one person is connected via a media player but nobody is watching their stream but it remains connected constantly even if i reboot ngnix it will reconnect. So it is currently at 56.74GB but can reach up to 500GB or more. Does this get charged as data transfer bill on my hosting of am i ok to forget about this?

Just want to understand best practises when using ngnix live streaming and try and reduce the costs of users using my server as much as possible.

Would love some good advise on this from any one doing something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the hosting providers themselves procure the traffic capacity wholesale for their clients, they usually have to pay on a 95th percentile utilisation scale, which means that if a 5-minute average utilisation is at or below 5Gbps 95% of the time, then they'll pay at a rate for 5Gbps for all of their traffic, even if consumption at about 04:00 in the morning is way below 1Gbps, nor at certain times of the day is way above 5Gbps for a spike of many minutes at a time -- they still pay for 5Gbps, which is their 95th percentile on a 5-minute average basis.

Another consideration is that links are usually symmetrical, whereas most hosting providers that host web-sites have very asymmetrical traffic patterns -- an average HTTP request is likely to be about 1KB, whereas a response will likely be around 10KB or more.

As for the first point above, as it's relatively difficult to calculate the 95th percentile usage for the clients individually, the providers absorb the cost, and charge their retail clients on a TB/month basis.  As for the second point, what this basically means is that in most circumstances, the incoming traffic is basically already paid for through the roof, and noone's using it, so, most providers only really charge for the outgoing traffic because of that.

Comment: in summary: in the example you provide, your idle user (whose stream is of no interest to anyone yet) is only using the incoming bandwidth of your server, which, with most hosters, comes for free

Comment: Thanks for the summary ;)